# how to count app online users and statistic user online time

Tags: oauth, asp.net-web-api

I designed a mobile app with a server side. The user is authorizated by OAuth, but how can I count the online users realtime, and how to statistic how long the user keep online.
After the user request an access token, every time the user access other resource in server should take this token, and the server side does not keep the access token. The access token has a long life time. So how should I design the sytem to make it can count the online users and the user online time.

Comment: Maybe I didn't described it clearly. I want to count the online users realtime, but the web api is designed stateless, how can I do it? A method is to record the access to database every time, then satistic it later. But this will cause a large io write to database. So are there some better methods to do it?